# How do you automatically Login to OWA 2013 using HTML + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, exchange-server

We used to use Exchange 2007 and the HTML + JavaScript below to log into OWA 2007 automatically.

But we've now upgraded to Exchange **2013** and the script no longer works. It displays **404 - File or directory not found.**
I've asked our Infrastructure department if the owaauth.dll file is still in the same location, and they have told me it's moved to:

```
https://" + server + "/exchweb/auth/owaauth.dll
```

I changed the script to use the new path, but I still get the `404 - File or directory not found` error.

My question is what do I need to change in the script to make it work with Exchange 2013?

**Here are the Exchange 2007 script details**

[HOWTO: Automatically Login to OWA 2007 using HTML + JavaScript](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vikas/archive/2009/06/03/howto-automatically-login-to-owa-2007-using-html-javascript.aspx)

```
<script>
function LoginToOWA (server,domain,username,password) {


  var url = "https://" + server + "/exchweb/bin/auth/owaauth.dll";
  var p = {destination:'https://' + server + '/exchange',flags:'0',forcedownlevel:'0',trusted:'0',isutf8:'1',username:domain + '\\' + username,password:password};


  var myForm = document.createElement("form");
  myForm.method="post" ;
  myForm.action = url ;

  for (var k in p) {

    var myInput = document.createElement("input") ;
    myInput.setAttribute("name", k) ;
    myInput.setAttribute("value", p[k]);
    myForm.appendChild(myInput) ;
  }


  document.body.appendChild(myForm) ;
  myForm.submit() ;
  document.body.removeChild(myForm) ;
}
</script>

<body onload="javascript:LoginToOWA('owa.exchange.com','domain','username','password');">
<h3>Please wait while redirecting to OWA...</h3>
</Body>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Worked it out. Here's the new script that works with OWA 2013:

```
<script>
function LoginToOWA (server,domain,username,password,useremailaddress) {

  var url = "https://" + server + "/owa/" + useremailaddress + "/auth/owaauth.dll"; 
  var p = {destination:'https://' + server + '/owa/#path=/mail',flags:'0',forcedownlevel:'0',trusted:'0',isutf8:'1',username:domain + '\\' + username,password:password};

  var myForm = document.createElement("form");
  myForm.method="post" ;
  myForm.action = url ;

  for (var k in p) {

    var myInput = document.createElement("input") ;
    myInput.setAttribute("name", k) ;
    myInput.setAttribute("value", p[k]);
    myForm.appendChild(myInput) ;
  }


  document.body.appendChild(myForm) ;
  myForm.submit() ;
  document.body.removeChild(myForm) ;
}
</script>

<body onload="javascript:LoginToOWA('owa.exchange.com','domain','username','password','user@emailaddress.com');">
<h3>Please wait while redirecting to OWA...</h3>
</Body>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for posting this, you just saved me a bunch of time